# Problemas con librerias gradle.bundle (Android Studio)

Tags: android, gradle

Buenos dias, tengo un problema que siempre me pasa. 
Es con el tema de agregar librerias al proyecto, por lo general me pasa cuando coloco varias librerias de google, al ejecutar me sale el error de compatibildidad en las librerias, creo que es porque hay librerias que utilizan el mismo modulo y por eso el error.
Estas son las librerias que uso en le proyecto:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile files('libs/poi-315.jar')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.2'
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile group: 'com.google.android', name: 'support-v4', version: 'r7'
```

El error de compilacion me sale cuando agrege esta libreria para poder incorporar Google Maps Api v2 en mi proyecto:

```
compile group: 'com.google.android', name: 'support-v4', version: 'r7'
```

Alguien que me diga porque pasa esto? Alguna buena practica para que no vuelva a pasar? Que cosas tengo que tener en cuenta a la hora de agregar librerias.

Este es el error que sale:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Yo noto 2 problemas que pueden tener varias causas:

> Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException:
>   Multiple dex files

y

> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 2

podría solucionarse mediante agregando en tu `build.gradle` :

```
dexOptions {
    ...
    preDexLibraries = false
    ...
}
```

y habilita el [soporte `MultiDex`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) ya que veo tienes varias librerías y el problema puede ser causado por la gran cantidad de métodos en tu proyecto :

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
        ...
    }
```

al final te recomiendo realices un `Clean` > `Rebuild all` y sincronices los `build.gradle` con tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Cómo indica [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23741983/1468942) parece ser que se puede resolver fácil. En el `build.gradle` en el `android block` agrega:

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```